# Relacionamento Muitos Para Muitos Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Bom dia,
Tenho as seguintes classes:

**CONSUL_CA_Aluno:**

```
public class CONSUL_CA_Aluno
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Cpf { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public int Ativo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CONSUL_CA_Curso> CONSUL_CA_Cursos { get; set; }
}
```

**CONSUL_CA_Curso:**

```
public class CONSUL_CA_Curso
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Ativo { get; set; }
    public string Ministrante { get; set; }
    public string Duracao { get; set; }
    public int CargaHoraria { get; set; }
    public string LocalCurso { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CONSUL_CA_Aluno> CONSUL_CA_Alunos { get; set; }
}
```

No banco de dados tenho a tabela CONSUL_CA_CursoAluno onde ficará armazenado os dados das classes.

Quando testo:

```
CONSUL_CA_Aluno aluno = new CONSUL_CA_Aluno();
aluno.Ativo = 1;
aluno.Cpf = 1321;
aluno.Email = "email";
aluno.Nome = "diididid";
aluno.Senha = "123";
aluno.CONSUL_CA_Cursos = contexto.Cursos.ToList();
aluno.CONSUL_CA_Cursos = aluno.CONSUL_CA_Cursos.Select(curso => contexto.Curso.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == curso.Id)).ToList();
contexto.Aluno.Add(aluno);
contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Apresenta o seguinte erro:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>   Additional information: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

Comment: Há alguma necessidade de usar esses nomes cifrados? `CONSUL_CA_Aluno` poderia ser substituído só por `Aluno`, não?

Comment: No banco de dados é utilizado essas nomenclaturas, então para manter o padrão, utilizei tbm!

Comment: Não é necessário. Você pode usar o *Attribute* [Table("CONSUL_CA_Aluno")] antes da declaração de classe `Aluno` que o Entity Framework faz o apontamento pra você.

Comment: Não conhecia. Certo, mas e quanto ao erro na inserção, alguma ajuda?

Comment: Estou escrevendo sua resposta. Só um momento.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O Entity Framework se perde na hora de definir a associação N para N, por mais que em teoria a declaração do seu `Model` esteja correta.

Há duas maneiras de resolver:

### 1. Usando Configuração Fluente no Model Builder

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>()
        .HasMany(a => a.Cursos)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(x =>
        {
            x.MapLeftKey("AlunoId");
            x.MapRightKey("CursoId");
            x.ToTable("AlunosCursos");
        });
```

O problema desta abordagem é que a tabela associativa é mínima. Você não poderá adicionar campos extras relativos à associação. A alteração é menor, mas funcionará para o código postado na pergunta.

### 2. Definindo uma entidade associativa

```
[Table("CONSUL_CA_Aluno")]
public class Aluno
{
    [Key]
    public int AlunoId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Cpf { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EMailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public Boolean Ativo { get; set; } /* troquei este para Boolean */

    public virtual ICollection<AlunoCurso> AlunosCursos { get; set; }
}

[Table("CONSUL_CA_Cursos")]
public class Curso 
{
    [Key]
    public int CursoId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public Boolean Ativo { get; set; } /* troquei este para Boolean */
    public string Ministrante { get; set; }
    public string Duracao { get; set; }
    public int CargaHoraria { get; set; }
    public string LocalCurso { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AlunoCurso> AlunosCursos { get; set; }
}

public class AlunosCursos
{
    [Key]
    public int AlunoCursoId { get; set; }
    public int AlunoId { get; set; }
    public int CursoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; }
    public virtual Curso Curso { get; set; }
}
```

#### No Controller

```
Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
// A linha de baixo não precisa colocar porque eu já defini o default no Model
// aluno.Ativo = true;
aluno.Cpf = 1321;
aluno.Email = "email";
aluno.Nome = "diididid";
aluno.Senha = "123";

contexto.Aluno.Add(aluno);
contexto.SaveChanges();

foreach (var curso in contexto.Cursos.ToList()) {
    var alunoCurso = new AlunoCurso();
    alunoCurso.Aluno = aluno;
    alunoCurso.Curso = curso;
    contexto.AlunosCursos.Add(alunoCurso);
    contexto.SaveChanges();
}

contexto.Entry(aluno).State = EntityState.Modified;
contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Neste caso, seu código deverá ser mudado para lidar com esta associação. Fica um pouco mais burocrático, mas é uma abordagem mais completa.

Comment: Para a segunda opção, você conhece algum tutorial, ou algo que eu pudesse acompanhar. Pois não sei como poderia lidar com essa opção.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Quer que eu coloque um exemplo de código? Assim você não perde o fio da meada.

Comment: Quero sim. Se possível.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Coloquei como fazer no Controller. Veja se atende.

Comment: Dúvida: O AlunoId e o CursoId não precisam ser setadas no controller? E toda vez que houver uma alteração no aluno x curso é necessário deletar todos os registros relacionados a aquele aluno e inserir tudo de novo?

Comment: @DiegoZanardo Não é recomendável. O contexto pode se perder e causar inserção duplicada de objetos. Use o objeto diretamente para seguir a convenção do Entity Framework e evitar problemas futuros.

Comment: Não entendi sua resposta!

Answer (score 3):

***Ta errada aqui:***

```
aluno.CONSUL_CA_Cursos = aluno.CONSUL_CA_Cursos.Select(curso => contexto.Curso.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == curso.Id)).ToList();
```

Você ta usando o `aluno` que é um objeto novo para buscar informação, não seria o contexto?, ou seja a classe que herdou de `DbContext`?

***Exemplo de utilização***

```
[Table("Livro")]
public class Livro
{
    public Livro()
    {
         this.Autores = new HashSet<Autor>();  
    }

    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Titulo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Autor> Autores { get; set;}
}

[Table("Autor")]
public class Autor
{
    public Autor()
    {
        this.Livros = new HashSet<Livro>();
    }

    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Livro> Livros {get;set;}
}
```

Essas entidades possui relacionamento `N - M` ou seja, muitos para muitos.

---

```
public class Context: DbContext
{
            public Context()
                : base("conexao") { }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Livro>()
                        .HasMany(l => l.Autores)
                        .WithMany(a => a.Livros)
                        .Map(x =>
                        {
                            x.MapLeftKey("LivroId");
                            x.MapRightKey("AutorId");
                            x.ToTable("LivroAutor");
                        });
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
            public DbSet<Livro> Livro { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Autor> Autor { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
//classe que herda de DbContext // EF6
Context db = new Context();

//Livro (Novo);
Livro livro = new Livro();
livro.Titulo = "Livro 1";


//Autor (Novo);
Autor autor = new Autor();
autor.Nome = "Autor 1";
// adicionando esse livro nesse autor muitos para muitos aqui ...
autor.Livros.Add(livro); 

//adicionando livro
db.Livro.Add(livro);

//adicionando autor
db.Autor.Add(autor);

//salvando todas alterações
db.SaveChanges();

db.Dispose();
```

Essa é um layout de muitos para muitos, agora se a tabela intermediária for diferente ela tem que ser exposta na Context (`DbSet<>`) para passagem dos valores adicionais.

Comment: Você diz isso?                 aluno.CONSUL_CA_Cursos =
                    contexto.Aluno.Select(curso => contexto.Curso.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == curso.Id)).ToList();

Comment: Sim, seria isso que ele quis dizer

Comment: testei aqui, e não deu certo!

Comment: Sim ... aluno seria uma nova instância entendeu ... se tem que pegar os cursos da classe que herda DbContext

Comment: Não deu certo. O mesmo erro!

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo de livro e autor onde livro pode ter vários autores e autores podem conter vários livros (`N - M`), se quiser observar Diego !!!