# Entity FrameWork relacionamento muitos x muitos campo extra

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Bom dia,

Estou estudando o Entity FrameWork Code First e estou na dúvida de como devo criar um modelo de NxN com uma informação extra na tabela de relacionamento. Por exemplo:

Vamos supor o seguinte relacionamento (imagem tirada do site da MSDN)

[image: Tabelas]

Até ai tudo bem, crio o modelo Person e Course e estabeleço a relação entre eles com o ICollection e "dizendo" que um Course tem vários Person e vice-versa e o EF cria este relacionamento (CourseInstructo).

Agora vamos supor que precise de uma informação extra qualquer na tabela CourseInstructo, por exemplo Ativo ou DataInicio.
Da forma proposta o EF cria a tabela automaticamente não possibilitando que eu adicione campo extra no relacionamento, certo?

Como eu deveria proceder para este caso?
Deveria criar 3 modelos:

- Person
- Course
- CourseInstructo

e estabelecer o relacionamento da Person e Course com CourseInstructo? Como seria o esboço desse código e depois a manipulação desses registros (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neste caso, você precisa de um tipo para setar este valor extra, impossibilitando você de ter acesso direto da sua classe `Person` ou `Course`.

Você pode tratar este relacionamento como uma nova [`Entidade de Agregação`](http://erealityhome.wordpress.com/2008/09/07/relacionamento-tipo-agregacao-entidade-tipo-associativa-2/), dado que esta informação irá ser pertinente a relação.

Entretanto, você deve realizar o tratamento manual desta entidade, bem como adiciona-la um novo `DbSet<CourseInstructor>` em seu contexto.

Em suas classes `Course` e `Person` você deve conter uma lista de `CourseInstructor`.

Por exemplo:

```
public class CourseInstructor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public string Extra { get; set; }

    public int InstructorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Instructor Instructor { get; set; } 
}
```

Um link que também pode te ajudar: [Relacionamento Muitos Para Muitos Entity Framework 6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14829/relacionamento-muitos-para-muitos-entity-framework-6)

Comment: fiz todo esse processo. Criei as classes e as relações conforme indicado. Cada uma com o seu DBSet no Context e o seu repositório. Funciona ao adicionar Person e Course mas ao adicionar a relação deles da erro.   CourseInstructor.Person = Person(previamente cadastrado) e o mesmo para Course e depois mando salvar.

Comment: Olá @Renato, se isto te ajudou a encontrar a solução para o problema. Lembre-se de marcar o post como solução, para ajudar outros usuários com um problema semelhante no futuro :)

Comment: Consegui identificar o problema. Obrigado. Gostaria de referenciar um lonk que também contribuiu. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14829/relacionamento-muitos-para-muitos-entity-framework-6

Answer (score 0):

Assim como o Felipe Oriani mencionou a crianção de uma nova classe "CourseInstructor", mas o Entity FrameWork Code First faz isso de forma automática vou dar um exemplo

```
        public class Person 
        {
            public Person ()
            {
                this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
            }

            [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int PersonId{ get; set; }
public strng lastName{ get; set; }
public strig firstName{ get; set; }



            public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }

        }
```

///

```
      public class Course 
        {
            public Course ()
            {
                this.Persons = new HashSet<Person>();
            }

            [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int CouserId{ get; set; }
public string Title{ get; set; }
//...


            public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

        }
```

Desta forma cria uma nova tabela no banco, sem você precisar criar uma nova class.
facilita que todas vez que tiver qualquer alteração em abas das classe, não necessita também fazer a alteração em uma outra classe com as mesmas informações.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim

```
    public class Course 
{

     [key]
     public int CourseId {get;set;}

     etc ....

     [ForeignKey("CourseID")]
     public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get;  set; }

}


public class Person 
{
    [key]
    public int PersonId {get;set;}

    etc...

    [ForeignKey("PersonID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get;  set; }
}


public class CourseInstructo 
{
   [key] // de preferencia com autoincremento
   public int CourseInstructoId {get;set;}


   [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
   public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
   public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

   [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
   public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }

   [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
   public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }

   //Campo extra

}
```