# Entity Framework 6, relacionamento muitos X muitos e Scaffolding

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou realizando um projeto de faculdade e meus conhecimentos em ASP.Net não são muito profundos. Em meu projeto me deparei com um relacionamento **MxM** e não consigo implementar de forma útil essa situação. O relacionamento é o seguinte:

- Uma empresa cadastra um ou mais pontos de coleta de lixo e no momento do cadastro ela escolhe um ou mais tipo de lixo aceitos em
  seu ponto de coleta.
- Um tipo de lixo pode ser usado no cadastro de vários pontos de coleta.
- Um ponto de coleta pode associar vários tipos de lixo que são aceitos.

Já tentei de inúmeras formas indicadas aqui neste site. Tentei desta forma [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14829/relacionamento-muitos-para-muitos-entity-framework-6) e criando a classe associativa manualmente, mas no scaffolding o Entity não gera a relação na view.

Fazendo da forma como indicado neste link [Aqui](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wriju/2011/05/14/code-first-ef-4-1-building-many-to-many-relationship/), O Entity Framework gerou a tabela associativa de forma automática, mas no scaffolding as views foram criadas com nenhuma associação. Nas relações 1xN o Entity cria automaticamente um `dropdowlist` para que seja selecionado na view.

1. Na relação MxM não deveria criar automaticamente um grupo de
   `checkbox` ou uma lista de seleção? (ou estou esperando muito do
   Entity...).
2. Caso não tenha como gerar essa feature automaticamente, como faria
   isso?
3. Após gerar o grupo de checkbox ou lista de seleção, como fazer para
   manipular a tabela associativa? (a tabela da classe em questão o
   Entity já criou o CRUD).

Segue o código:

```
[Table("PontoDeColeta")]
public class PontoDeColeta
{
    public PontoDeColeta()
    {
        TipoDeLixo = new HashSet<TipoDeLixo>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O prenchimento é obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome popular*: ")]
    public string NomePopular { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O prenchimento é obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Endereço do ponto de coleta*: ")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    //Armazena usuário logado
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string UsuarioResponsavel { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TipoDeLixo> TipoDeLixo { get; set; }
}
[Table("TipoDeLixo")]
public class TipoDeLixo
{
    public TipoDeLixo()
    {
        PontoDeColeta = new HashSet<PontoDeColeta>();
    }
    //[Key]
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="O prenchimento é obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome do tipo de lixo*: ")]
    public string NomeTipoLixo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Este tipo de lixo está ativo? ")]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PontoDeColeta> PontoDeColeta { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**:
Seguindo a melhor resposta do comentário, tive que alterar minhas classes além de criar a classe associativa manualmente.

```
public class TipoDeLixo{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage ="O prenchimento é obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome do tipo de lixo*: ")]
    public string NomeTipoLixo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Este tipo de lixo está ativo? ")]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }


    public ICollection<PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo> PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo {  get; set; }

}

public class PontoDeColeta{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O prenchimento é obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome popular*: ")]
    public string NomePopular { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo> PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo { get; set; }
     }

public class PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual TipoDeLixo TipoDeLixo { get; set; }

    public Guid TipoDeLixoId { get; set; }

    public virtual PontoDeColeta PontoDeColeta { get; set; }

    public Guid PontoDeColetaId { get; set; }
    }
```

Na View Create do PontoDeColeta:

```
 @Html.Partial("_TiposDeLixo",Model.PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo)
```

Criei a PartialView _TipoDeLixo com o conteúdo:

```
@model IEnumerable<IdentitySample.Models.PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo>

<div class="actions">
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="adicionar-tipo-de-lixo">
    Adicionar Tipo de lixo
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#adicionar-tipo-de-lixo").click(function () {
                $.get('/PontosDeColeta/NovaLinhaDeTipoDeLixo', function (template) {
                    $("#area-tipos-de-lixo").append(template);
                });
            });
</script>
</div>

<div id="area-tipos-de-lixo">
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var lixo in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_LinhaTipoDeLixo", lixo);
    }
}
</div>
```

Depois criei a PartiaView _LinhaTipoDeLixo com o conteúdo:

```
@model IdentitySample.Models.PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("TipoDeLixo"))
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TipoDeLixoId)

    <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Nome</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TipoDeLixo.NomeTipoLixo, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Nome" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoDeLixo.NomeTipoLixo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a class="btn red" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();">Excluir</a>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

E no PontoDeColetaController criei a Action com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
public ActionResult NovaLinhaDeTipoDeLixo()
    {
        return PartialView("_TiposDeLixo", new PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo { Id = Guid.NewGuid() });
    }
```

Então quando rodo o sistema, aparece o seguinte erro:

*The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'IdentitySample.Models.PontoDeColeta', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[IdentitySample.Models.PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo]'.*

**EDIT**: Tirei um print da tela com o erro.
[image: Print com o erro]
**ATUALIZAÇÃO DO CONTROLLER** PontoDeColetaController completo:

```
namespace IdentitySample.Controllers
{
public class PontosDeColetaController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();


    // GET: PontosDeColeta
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult NovaLinhaDeTipoDeLixo()
    {
        return PartialView("_LinhaTipoDeLixo", new PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo { Id = Guid.NewGuid() });
    }


    //Lista os potos de coleta de acordo com parametros passados
    public JsonResult Listar(string searchPhrase, int current = 1, int rowCount = 5)
    {
        var Identificacao = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
        var Pontos = (from u in db.PontoDeColeta
                      where u.UsuarioResponsavel == Identificacao
                      select u);
        string Chave = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(v => v.StartsWith("sort")).First();

        string Ordenacao = Request[Chave];

        string Coluna = Chave.Replace("sort[", String.Empty).Replace("]",String.Empty);

        var Soma = Pontos.Count();

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchPhrase))
        {
            Pontos = Pontos.Where("NomePopular.Contains(@0) OR Endereco.Contains(@0) OR Cidade.Contains(@0) OR Estado.Contains(@0) OR Apelido.Contains(@0)", searchPhrase);
        }

        string ColunaOrdenacao = String.Format("{0} {1}", Coluna, Ordenacao);

        var PontoDeColetaPagina = Pontos.OrderBy(ColunaOrdenacao).Skip((current - 1) * rowCount).Take(rowCount);

        return Json(new{
            rows = PontoDeColetaPagina.ToList(),
            current = current,
            rowCount = rowCount,
            total = Soma
        }
        , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    // GET: PontosDeColeta/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        PontoDeColeta pontoDeColeta = db.PontoDeColeta.Find(id);
        if (pontoDeColeta == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return PartialView(pontoDeColeta);
    }

    // GET: PontosDeColeta/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var UsuarioLogado = new PontoDeColeta();
        UsuarioLogado.UsuarioResponsavel = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        return View(UsuarioLogado);
    }

    // POST: PontosDeColeta/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,NomePopular,Endereco,Cidade,Estado,Latitude,Longitude,Remuneracao,InfoAdicional,Ativo,Apelido,UsuarioResponsavel")] PontoDeColeta pontoDeColeta)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            pontoDeColeta.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            db.PontoDeColeta.Add(pontoDeColeta);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(pontoDeColeta);
    }

    // GET: PontosDeColeta/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        PontoDeColeta pontoDeColeta = db.PontoDeColeta.Find(id);
        if (pontoDeColeta == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        pontoDeColeta.UsuarioResponsavel = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        return View(pontoDeColeta);
    }

    // POST: PontosDeColeta/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,NomePopular,Endereco,Cidade,Estado,Latitude,Longitude,InfoAdicional,Ativo,Apelido,UsuarioResponsavel")] PontoDeColeta pontoDeColeta)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(pontoDeColeta).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(pontoDeColeta);
    }

    // GET: PontosDeColeta/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        PontoDeColeta pontoDeColeta = db.PontoDeColeta.Find(id);
        if (pontoDeColeta == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView(pontoDeColeta);
    }

    // POST: PontosDeColeta/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
    {
        PontoDeColeta pontoDeColeta = db.PontoDeColeta.Find(id);
        db.PontoDeColeta.Remove(pontoDeColeta);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Já tentei de inúmeras formas indicadas aqui neste site. Tentei desta forma [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14829/relacionamento-muitos-para-muitos-entity-framework-6) e criando a classe associativa manualmente, mas no scaffolding o Entity não gera a relação na view.

Em que sentido não gera? Se for uma relação mestre-detalhe, não gera mesmo. O *Scaffolding* pode ser meio limitado em algumas situações.

> 1. Na relação MxM não deveria criar automaticamente um grupo de checkbox ou uma lista de seleção? (ou estou esperando muito do Entity...).

Está esperando muito do mecanismo de *Scaffolding*, na verdade. Infelizmente, até então, esta implementação é manual. Já tentei algumas vezes produzir um *Scaffold* para esse caso, mas é bem complicado. Ainda não achei solução satisfatória. Se eu achar, prometo voltar aqui e propor uma solução.

> 2. Caso não tenha como gerar essa feature automaticamente, como faria isso?

Usando o pacote [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/). [Veja aqui as respostas já dadas sobre ele no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+begincollectionitem). [Esta é minha melhor resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129911/passar-dois-modelos-para-uma-view-de-cadastro/129912#129912).

> 3. Após gerar o grupo de checkbox ou lista de seleção, como fazer para manipular a tabela associativa? (a tabela da classe em questão o Entity já criou o CRUD).

Depende do *Controller*. Se for um *Controller* da própria tabela de associação, é trivial. Se for o *Controller* de `PontoDeColeta`, siga minha melhor resposta que tem exemplos de como fazer.

---

**PÓS EDIT**

Tudo certo na sua implementação, exceto isto aqui:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("TipoDeLixo"))
```

Se `@model` de `Create` é `PontoDeColeta`, o nome da *collection* não pode ser "TipoDeLixo" porque não existe uma propriedade de navegação com este nome aqui:

```
public class PontoDeColeta
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O prenchimento é obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome popular*: ")]
    public string NomePopular { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo> PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo { get; set; } // <---- Você quis usar esta propriedade, provavelmente
 }
```

Então deveria ser:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo"))
```

---

**PÓS EDIT 2**

O objeto indo para a *Partial View* está nulo. `PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo` precisa ser inicializado para funcionar.

```
// GET: PontosDeColeta/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var pontoDeColeta = new PontoDeColeta 
    {
        UsuarioResponsavel = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
        PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo = new List<PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo>()
    };

    return View(pontoDeColeta);
}
```

A mensagem de erro é meio traiçoeira mesmo. Como `PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo` estava nulo, o MVC tenta passar o objeto pai. É um erro bastante comum quando se usa *Partials*.

Comment: Editei a pergunta complementando tudo que fiz com base em sua resposta.

Comment: @VictorProjetoFinal Quase certo. Veja a expansão da minha resposta.

Comment: Fiz a alteração:

Comment: Fiz a alteração: `@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo"))` e ainda notei que na action do controller estava chamando a PartialView errada. O correto é `return PartialView("_LinhaTiposDeLixo", new PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo { Id = Guid.NewGuid() });`. Porém mesmo assim o sistema apresenta o mesmo erro. Já comparei o código todo e não vi nada errado.

Comment: Tem certeza de que é esta mensagem, exatamente escrita desta forma? `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'IdentitySample.Models.PontoDeColeta', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[IdentitySample.Models.PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo]'.` Acho que os tipos são diferentes. Preciso da nova mensagem de erro.

Comment: Tirei um print agora e editei na pergunta. Será que não são os atributos das classes? É a única diferença que vi de seu exemplo.

Comment: O erro é claro. O que você está passando para a *Partial* é uma variável do tipo `PontoDeColeta`, e por mais que o nome esteja correto, você não está passando `IEnumerable<PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo>`. Edite sua pergunta e coloque também o código do *Controller*.

Comment: Coloquei o código completo do controller

Comment: @VictorProjetoFinal Você caiu numa das mensagens mais traiçoeiras do ASP.NET MVC. Veja minha edição.