# DropdownList com BeginCollectionItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dropdownlist

Boa Noite!

Poderia seguir [nesta mesma pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198456/entity-framework-6-relacionamento-muitos-x-muitos-e-scaffolding), mas iria ficar muito longo. Como pode ser outro assunto resolvi abrir outra pergunta.

Consegui tudo certo conforme [a melhor resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129911/passar-dois-modelos-para-uma-view-de-cadastro/129912#129912), mas precisaria fazer uma alteração. Cada campo novo adicionado não poderia ser digitado. Ele deveria ser preenchido com dados já cadastrados no banco de dados. Explicando melhor: No cadastro de ponto de coleta, o usuário não deve criar quantos tipos de lixo quiser, e sim selecionar os tipos de lixo disponíveis previamente cadastrados no banco de dados.

Para tal tentei trocar o TextBoxFor por uma DropDownList. Mas cada vez que tento adicionar um novo campo o sistema apresenta um erro.

*An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Valor não pode ser nulo.*

No controller possuo o código:

```
 ViewBag.Lixo = db.TipoDeLixo.ToList();
```

E na PartialView troquei o código:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TipoDeLixo.NomeTipoLixo, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Nome" })
```

Por:

```
@Html.ListBox("Id",(SelectList)ViewBag.Lixo)
```

Tentei outras formas com ListBox, tentei com ListBox sem usar o esquema das PartialViews, tentei com MultiSelectList e várias outras formas.

Sem utilizar o esquema das PartialViews, o sistema até lista os tipos de lixo, mas depois eu não consegui pensar em como gravar as informações na tabela de Ponto de coleta e na tabela associativa (PontosDeColetaTipoDeLixo).

1)Como fazer que cada campo adicionado seja um DropDownList?

2)Após conseguir criar, como seria a melhor forma para editar?

**EDIT1:** Criação da partial na view `Create`:

```
@Html.Partial("_TiposDeLixo", Model.PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo)
```

Partial que chama as linhas `_TiposDeLixo`:

```
@model IEnumerable<IdentitySample.Models.PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo>


<div class="actions">
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="adicionar-tipo-de-lixo">
    Adicionar Tipo de lixo
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#adicionar-tipo-de-lixo").click(function () {
                $.get('/PontosDeColeta/NovaLinhaDeTipoDeLixo', function (template) {
                    $("#area-tipos-de-lixo").append(template);
                    console.log(template);
                });
            });
</script>
</div>

<div id="area-tipos-de-lixo">
@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var lixo in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_LinhaTipoDeLixo", lixo);
    }
}
</div>
```

Partial da linha `_LinhaTipoDeLixo`:

```
@model IdentitySample.Models.PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo


@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo"))
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TipoDeLixoId)

    <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Nome</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">

       @Html.ListBox("Id", new SelectList((List<IdentitySample.Models.TipoDeLixo>)ViewBag.Lixo))

     </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a class="btn red" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();">Excluir</a>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Action do controller que chama a nova linha:

```
 public ActionResult NovaLinhaDeTipoDeLixo()
    {
        return PartialView("_LinhaTipoDeLixo", new PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo { Id = Guid.NewGuid() });
    }
```

Comment: Pode colocar na sua pergunta o código completo da *Partial*?

Comment: Resposta editada. Aproveito para agradecer as dicas que tem me dado até aqui.

Comment: Tudo certo. Agora preciso também do método do *Controller* que gera uma linha nova (a *Action* `NovaLinhaDeTipoDeLixo`).

Comment: Pronto. Atualizado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não definiu a `ViewBag` no retorno da *Partial*. Naturalmente vai ter erro de referência nula:

```
public ActionResult NovaLinhaDeTipoDeLixo()
{
    ViewBag.Lixo = db.TiposDeLixo.ToList();
    return PartialView("_LinhaTipoDeLixo", new PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo { Id = Guid.NewGuid() });
}
```

Comment: Perfeito funcionou. Estava agora pensando no "editar", tem como fazer com o mesmo esquema? Tipo como eu adicionaria as linhas de acordo com os tipos de lixo que o usuário já cadastrou? Elas já teriam que vir adicionadas certo?

Comment: É análogo. Se precisar de ajuda, faça outra pergunta que explico isso em detalhes pra você (já digo que vai ficar um pouco longo).

Comment: Pronto. Fiz uma outra pergunta. [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203107/como-fazer-adi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dados-utilizando-begincollection-e-partialviews]. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, altere seu código da seguinte maneira:

```
@Html.ListBox("Id", new SelectList((List<SeuNamespace.Lixo>)ViewBag.Lixo))
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado! Mas infelizmente aparece a mesma mensagem.