# Como fazer adição de dados utilizando BeginCollection e PartialViews

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partialview

Consegui fazer o sistema com inserção de dados com BeginCollection e PartialViews conforme [visto nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201626/dropdownlist-com-begincollectionitem/202870?noredirect=1#comment415957_202870). Dando continuidade a mesma, como faria a parte de edição dos dados cadastrados no banco de dados?

Exemplo: Cadastrei um ponto de coleta com dois tipos de lixo (plastico e papel). Posteriormente, quero incluir outro tipo de lixo (alumínio). Como fazer para as linhas já virem preenchidas com os dados escolhidos previamente?

**EDIT1:** Segue o print com dois erros. Ele não consegue encontrar a definição de TipoDeLixo e de PontoDeColetaId. Mas eles existem na Collection.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O restante do código adaptei algumas coisas e está OK.

---

**EDIT1:** Segue o print com dois erros. Ele não consegue encontrar a definição de TipoDeLixo e de PontoDeColetaId. Mas eles existem na `Collection`.

[image: Erro no TipoDeLixo][image: Erro no PontoDeColetaId]

O restante do código adaptei algumas coisas e está OK.

Comment: teria como postar o código novamente aqui, juntamente com o seu controler de edit.

Comment: Qual a chave de `PontoDeColeta`? Não é `PontoDeColetaId`? Eu estou seguindo [o que você colocou aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198456/entity-framework-6-relacionamento-muitos-x-muitos-e-scaffolding).

Comment: Ah, é só `Id` a chave. Por isso o erro. Vou modificar a resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Começando pela sua edição:

```
// GET: PontosDeColeta/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
{

    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    // Estou modificando esta linha
    var pontoDeColeta = db.PontoDeColeta
                          .Include(pc => pc.PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo.Select(pctl => pctl.TipoDeLixo))
                          .FirstOrDefault(pc => pc.Id == id);

    if (pontoDeColeta == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    pontoDeColeta.UsuarioResponsavel = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    // Aqui também.
    ViewBag.Lixo = db.TiposDeLixo.ToList();
    return View(pontoDeColeta);
}
```

No `POST`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
// Atenção ao Bind!
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,NomePopular,Endereco,Cidade,Estado,Latitude,Longitude,InfoAdicional,Ativo,Apelido,UsuarioResponsavel,PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo")] PontoDeColeta pontoDeColeta)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(pontoDeColeta).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        // Tipos de Lixo Originais
        var tiposDeLixoOriginais = db.PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo.AsNoTracking().Where(pctl => pctl.Id == pontoDeColeta.Id).ToList();

        // Tipos de Lixo Excluídos
        foreach (var tipoDeLixoOriginal in tiposDeLixoOriginais)
        {
            if (!pontoDeColeta.PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo.Any(pctl => pctl.PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixoId == tipoDeLixoOriginal.PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixoId))
        {
            var tipoDeLixoExcluido = db.PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo.Single(pctl => pctl.Id == tipoDeLixoOriginal.Id);
            db.PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo.Remove(tipoDeLixoExcluido);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    // Tipos de Lixo Inseridos
    foreach (var tipoDeLixo in pontoDeColeta.PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo)
    {
        if (!tiposDeLixoOriginais.Any(pctl => pctl.Id == tipoDeLixo.Id))
        {
            // Tipo de Lixo associado não existe ainda. Inserir.
            tipoDeLixo.PontoDeColetaId = pontoDeColeta.Id;
            db.PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo.Add(tipoDeLixo);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // Se a atualização falhar, você precisa carregar de novo os tipos de lixo.
    ViewBag.Lixo = db.TiposDeLixo.ToList();
    return View(pontoDeColeta);
}
```

Comment: Neste trecho: `// Estou modificando esta linha
    var pontoDeColeta = db.PontoDeColeta
                          .Include(pc => pc.PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo.TipoDeLixo)
                          .FirstOrDefault(pc => pc.PontoDeColetaId == id);` No  `pc.PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo.TipoDeLixo` ele apresenta erro dizendo que não encontra a definição de TipoDeLixo. Vou editar a pergunta com os prints.

Comment: O exemplo que eu coloquei não é só copiar e colar. Você tem que usar as chaves de acordo com seus *Models*. Editei com base na sua primeira pergunta.

Comment: Acho melhor você [fazer meu curso, em que eu explico todas essas coisas](http://www.codingcraft.com.br/2016/08/10/coding-craft-asp-net-mvc-e-asp-net-web-api-modulo-1-turma-de-10-de-setembro-de-2016/).

Comment: Correto. Eu adaptei o código. Apenas não me atentei no `PontoDeColetaId`. O restante eu já tinha alterado antes. Apenas o Erro no `TipoDeLixo` continua. Eu entendi a lógica do código mas fiquei em dúvida realmente nessa parta onde está o erro. Com esse código `pc => pc.PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo.TipoDeLixo`seria para preencher a collection com os lixos que já foram selecionados pelo usuário? Por que parece que ele não encontra os tipos de lixo dentro da collection.

Comment: Ah, sim. É que a cardinalidade de `PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo` é N, então na verdade tem que usar `.Include(pc => pc.PontosDeColetaTiposDeLixo.Select(pctl => pctl.TipoDeLixo))`. Já ajustei a resposta.

Comment: Ficou faltando fechar uma chave em: `return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}//Ficou faltando essa chave
    // Se a atualização falhar, você precisa carregar de novo os tipos de lixo.
    ViewBag.Lixo = db.TiposDeLixo.ToList(); `

Comment: Porém corrigindo o fechamento da chave, no momento de salvar a edição, uma mensagem de erro é apresentada: __An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'PontoDeColeta.Id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'PontoDeColetaTipoDeLixo.PontoDeColetaId' on the other end.__

Comment: Acho que identifiquei o problema. Parece que quando você adiciona novos tipos de lixo na edição, o PontoDeColetaId está ficando nulo na linha adicionada.

Comment: Você pode corrigir essa parte em *Controller*, se preferir.